# Replacing LVL beams by some lower depth ones

Tags: beam

We are planing a roof opening to access our roof top deck.

We were advised to use 3 ply LVL 1 3/4 x 11 7/8 beams.

Can we replace this with something shorter and wider (like 4 ply LVL 7 1/4) in order to reduce the overall height ?

Comment: Probably not unless you go with steel. Height is critical, and 7" is just too short for your span if it calls for a tripled 12".  Cutting height by almost half would call for more than doubling width, and that's a very non-standard arrangement. That said, we're not the place to ask. You need an engineer's signature. VTC.

Answer (score 2):

Probably not.  Height adds much more strength than width does.  A beam that is 1 3/4 x 11 7/8 has an I of 975 [I = (b*h^3)/3].  A 7 1/4" tall beam would need to be ~7 3/4" wide to provide roughly the same capacity (as @isherwood said, WE ARE NOT PROFESSIONAL ENGINEERS).  This seems that it would be more inconvenient to your design.